# How do I create a OAuth2 Spring Config without an Issuer-uri?

Tags: spring, security, spring-oauth2

I'm trying to authenticate with Jobber using OAuth2 from a Spring Java app.
I have these settings in the application.yml based on their documention https://developer.getjobber.com/docs/building_your_app/app_authorization

```
security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          oidc:
            authorization-uri:  https://api.getjobber.com/api/oauth/authorize
            token-uri:  https://api.getjobber.com/api/oauth/token
        registration:
          oidc:
            client-id: xxx
            client-secret: xxx
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            scope: clients, invoices, users, offline_access # last one for refresh tokens
            redirect-uri: http://localhost:9000/login/oauth2/code/oidc
```

I'm modifying code that works with an "issuer-uri" which provides those parameters in a .well-known/openid-configuration response, but my attempt, based on the spring docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/login/core.html, of editing the security chain:

```
.and()
            .oauth2Login() //modify the oauth2 parameters to handle the jobber config
            .oauth2ResourceServer()
                .jwt()
                .jwtAuthenticationConverter(authenticationConverter())
                .and()
            .and()
                .oauth2Client();
```

with

```
.and()
            .oauth2Login(  oauth2LoginCustomizer()) //modify the oauth2 parameters to handle the jobber config
            .oauth2ResourceServer()
                .jwt()
                .jwtAuthenticationConverter(authenticationConverter())
                .and()
            .and()
                .oauth2Client();

...

 Customizer<OAuth2LoginConfigurer<HttpSecurity>> oauth2LoginCustomizer(){
        return (oauth2Login) -> oauth2Login
            .userInfoEndpoint(userInfo -> userInfo
                .userAuthoritiesMapper(userAuthoritiesMapper())
            );
        }
```

and removing the method that uses the issuer-uri:

```
@Bean
    JwtDecoder jwtDecoder(ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository, RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
        NimbusJwtDecoder jwtDecoder = JwtDecoders.fromOidcIssuerLocation(issuerUri);

        OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> audienceValidator = new AudienceValidator(jHipsterProperties.getSecurity().getOauth2().getAudience());
        OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> withIssuer = JwtValidators.createDefaultWithIssuer(issuerUri);
        OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> withAudience = new DelegatingOAuth2TokenValidator<>(withIssuer, audienceValidator);

        jwtDecoder.setJwtValidator(withAudience);
        jwtDecoder.setClaimSetConverter(
            new CustomClaimConverter(clientRegistrationRepository.findByRegistrationId("oidc"), restTemplateBuilder.build())
        );

        return jwtDecoder;
    }
```

gives the exception:

```
Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method 'filterChain' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoder' available
```

How do I modify the config to use just the parameters provided by Jobber?

Answer (score 0):

> How do I create a OAuth2 Spring Config without an Issuer-uri?

The answer for:

- an OAuth2 client: authorization and token URIs are enough
- a resource server: you provide the JWK-set URI

However, I did not find a reference to issuer or JWK-set URIs for `getjobber`. Additionally, in their documentation, Bearer tokens are opaque (not JWTs) and introspection endpoint is not documented.

It is very likely that they reserve their authorization server for their own resource servers. Understand that you won't be able to configure efficiently a resource server of your own to authorize requests with Bearer tokens issued by `getjobber`: if you want to authenticate users with OAuth2, **you'll need an authorization server of your own**.

You might pick an on premise solution (Keycloak is a famous one), a cloud offer (like Auth0, Amazon Cognito and many others), or opt "for do it yourself" with spring-authorization-server.

Two options after you have configured your resource server with your authorization server:

- all API calls to getjobber are sent with the same service account (and good news, [it seems to be the case](https://www.jobbers.com/restoneapi/docs/index.html#authentication)): change your OAuth2 client configuration to `authorization-grant-type: client_credentials` (not `authorization_code`). If your app is just a REST API, also remove everything related to login from your resource server security filter-chain (login is not the responsibility of resource servers).
- API calls to getjobber must be sent on behalf of each user. Then two sub-options:

  - your OAuth2 client is written with a framework capable of handling client multi-tenancy: then have your user authenticate against both your authorization server and getjobber one, and send request to each resource server with the right access token
  - your OAuth2 client is written with Spring (Thymeleaf pages or `spring-cloud-gateway`), then you are a bit in trouble because of [this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/12862) (please upvote and detail your use-case there, to increase the chances that Spring Security team consider it some day). In that case, I suggest that you have a look at ["my" starter](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master) which configures an alternate `OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository` supporting multiple identities in the same user session (identity issued by getjobber and identity issued by your own authorization server).